# Is writing "System.AppContext" in code behind not supported in .net 4.5.1?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, app-config

I need long path support for my `.net 4.5.1` WPF application.

This setting in `App.config` works (long paths are supported):

```
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false" />
</runtime>
```

So I tried to set in in code, but it does not change the behaviour:

```
public App()
{
    // returns correct type:
    Type type = Type.GetType("System.AppContext"); 
    if (type != null)
    {
        // returns correct switch:
        MethodInfo setSwitch = type.GetMethod("SetSwitch", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        setSwitch.Invoke(null, new object[] { "Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling", false });
        setSwitch.Invoke(null, new object[] { "Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths", false });
    }
}
```

Is that "code behind setting" not supported in .net 4.5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that "code behind setting" not supported in .net 4.5.1?

No, it isn't. You should use [AppContext.SetSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.setswitch?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) to set the switches programmatically but since this API was introduced in .NET Framework 4.6, the only officially supported way to set the switches on earlier versions is to use the `App.config` file.